# how to extend loading process of webview

Tags: android, webview

I am loading a `web view` in android, initially it loads a `URL` it shows for 3-4 seconds and then automatically redirected to `another URL`, I just want to **skip** the `first URL displaying` by extending the web view loading...

I have used  method

```
shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url);
```

I also tried the `handler postdealy()` method but of no use...

Comment: Can you elaborate your situation. Is your first url is fix one?

Comment: hey i found the solution i just make webview **invisible** on `onLoadResource` and make it **visible** in `onPageFinished` after 3 second using handlers postdelay method